# XamarinForms-error CS0246:El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'X' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

hoy en la mañna tuve este problema y no he logrado solucionarlo, entiendo que el error **CS0246**  indica que me falta alguna referencia, he tratado de agregar y quitar la referencia de la solición pero no he obtenido nada ... y ya no se qué hacer. Esto me paso al reiniciar mi equipo por alguna razón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya probé borrar el caché, recompliar, limpiar la solución y antes me mandaba un millar de errores, pero estos son los únicos persistentes.

```
//MainActivity.cs

using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DatePickerService.Droid {
  [Activity(Label = "DatePickerService", Icon = "@drawable/calen", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
  public class MainActivity: global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
      TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
      ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

      base.OnCreate(bundle);

      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
      LoadApplication(new App());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Esos atributos pertenecen a la clase `ActivityAttribute` que se encuentra en el namespace de `Android.App`. No podras utilizarlo sin antes utiizar el namespace mencionado. Intenta utilizar: `using Android.App;` en la cabecera del código.

Comment: sorry mi error por no poner el code completo deja actualizo , en efecto estoy usando **Android.App**

Answer (score 1):

Primero quite la referencia

```
using Android.App;
```

posteriormente volvi a referencialo y se soluciono el problema